# Hadoop Cluster Cannot Remove TaskTracker node,

Tags: hadoop

The Hadoop Version is :

```
[hadoop@L-6140-BBS: ~/src/hadoop/conf]$ hadoop version
Hadoop 0.20.1+169.89
```

And I run the mradmin freshNodes,But it looks no this command

```
[hadoop@L-6140-BBS: ~/src/hadoop/conf]$ hadoop mradmin -refreshNodes
efreshNodes: Unknown command
Usage: java MRAdmin
       [-refreshServiceAcl]
       [-help [cmd]]

Generic options supported are
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
-jt <local|jobtracker:port>    specify a job tracker
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to         be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.

The general command line syntax is
bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using such an old version of Hadoop? It's a bit difficult to identify what the correct answer for you is, given how old your version is. The logs you've pasted suggest that `java mradmin` only has `-refreshServiceAcl` and `-help` options, so it's not surprising that you can't run `-refresNodes`.

Comment: @BenWatson emm,finally I find out that this version hadoop don't need mradmin refreshNodes,This System finished many years ago,And I just take it.